# Permission denied while trying to delete old Dropbox folder

Tags: permissions, dropbox

I have an old Dropbox folder that I don't want to use anymore.

No matter what I try, I keep on receiving "permission denied" while trying to remove it. I could remove its content easily, except **a single folder, that used to be shared with another Dropbox user**.

I uninstalled Dropbox completely, I rebooted the computer, but this folder still won't go away.

I have all the NTFS permissions on the folder. Even "Everyone" has all the permission on the folder and its subcontent :

[image]

The weirdest thing is that when I try to delete the folder the error says that I need a permission from (SomeUser). This is the user I'm logged in with ...

**I'm even the owner of the folder**

How can I finally get rid of this folder ?

Comment: Did you try to open it with administration rights?

Comment: I am logged in with the administrator account.

Comment: I know, but sometimes there is the need to still run it with administration rights. It says in English: "Run as administrator" when right clicked. So open Dropbox with administration rights and try again.

Comment: It shouldn't matter, but anyway, I delete my folders with a CMD ran as administrator, so the privileges are there

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that worked for me to delete these files that were previously shared with me, but I reinstalled the OS, and I did not have permission just like you.

These files have to be deleted one by one.
Right click on the file > properties > Security > Advanced (bottom right button)

In the new window that pops up if you have a first entry that is:

- Type: Deny
- Principal: Everyone
- Access: *Special* (this is most important as the Special is given a Deny, at least for me)

*Click the Remove button with this row selected*

- Click OK
- Click OK again
- Now try to delete it in the File Explorer (worked for me)

Answer (score -1):

You can install [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) if not already then navigate to the folder above the one you are trying to delete.

The command `rm -rf folder_name` will force the removal of the folder.

Comment: This still yields a permission denied error.

Comment: It's too early to suggest these complex things. It can be fixed in a probably much easier way.

Comment: Anyway, Cygwin is still on top of NTFS permissions, so this wouldn't have worked